# Can not calculate needed result

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySql. I have tables :

mails

```
id | user_id | date
1      2       2012/08/21
2      2       2012/08/22
```

calls

```
id | user_id | date 
 1     2       2012/08/21
 2     2       2012/08/21
```

i want to get SUM of calls and mails for user for some date. e.g:

```
date       | SUM
2012/08/21   3
2012/08/22   1
```

Comment: what was the query you were trying, btw?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT date, COUNT(1) SUM
FROM (SELECT user_id, date FROM mails 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT user_id, date FROM calls) t
GROUP BY date
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33fb2/2).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the columns id, user_id and date have the same data types in both tables:

```
SELECT date, count(id) as Sum FROM
(
  SELECT id, user_id, date from mails
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, user_id, date from calls
) total
WHERE user_id = 2
GROUP BY total.date
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7132f/11)

Comment: But if i dont have mails or calls, will i get empty result?

Comment: This will not account for a mail and a call that happened on the same date. Use `UNION ALL` instead.